# Return a 2D vector from a function

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to return a 2D vector from a function, but i receive the "there is no user defined conversion" error.

```
std::vector<double> fillMatrix(double *data, int rows, int cols) {
    std::vector < std::vector<double> > matrix;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        std::vector<double>temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp.push_back(data[cnt++]);
        }
        matrix.push_back(temp);
    }
    return  matrix;
}
```

Comment: Just change the return type of your function to `std::vector < std::vector<double> >`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the function to return a 2D vector you should not declare it to return an *1D* vector. I.e., it should be

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> fillMatrix(double *data, int rows, int cols) {
```

---

However, **I strongly recommend not to do so**. If return value optimization is not available for some reason, there will be a significant overhead by the invocation of `rows + 1` copy constructors of `vector` at the return statement. If things go worse another `rows + 1` copy constructors are called at the assignment operator, e.g. `myMatrix = fillMatrix(...)`.

Furthermore, the statement `matrix.push_back(temp)` also copies all the elements in temp.

Dealing with large objects you should consider to pass objects by reference rather than by value. Use smart pointers to do the memory management or pass the target object as reference to `fillMatrix` rather than assigning the return value.

---

At least the function name is misleading. It *creates* a matrix rather than filling one. The signature of `fillMatrix` should be like

```
void fillMatrix(const double *data, std::vector<std::vector<double>> &matrix) {
```

Note that there is no more need for the `rows` and `cols` parameter, since the matrix already has its size. Of course, you should not populate the matrix with `push_back()` in this case.